# Conditions useful for proving paracompactness

Tags: gn.general-topology, soft-question, paracompactness

I have a family of properties which I want to show taken together imply paracompactness (I can show that they are all implied by paracompactness). I can prove a whole bunch of things which are consequences of paracompactness, and was wondering if given any of these there's some simpler property equivalent to paracompactness I could prove. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Given X with these properties I can prove:

- X is normal
- X is countably paracompact
- X is collectionwise normal
- Every open cover $\{ U_a \}$ can be shrunk to a closed cover $\{ F_a \}$ with $F_a \subseteq U_a$. (I assume this property isn't equivalent to paracompactness? I know it's equivalent to countable paracompactness when the set of $U_a$ is countable, and I know if you add "locally finite" to the condition it becomes equivalent to paracompactness)
- Every open cover of X by $\kappa$ many open sets, where $\kappa$ is regular, has an open refinement which is locally $< \kappa$.

I don't think together these are sufficient to prove paracompactness, though I don't have a counter example. I believe $\omega_1$ satisfies all the properties but the last, though I've not confirmed you can shrink open covers to closed (it looks plausible though).

Any suggestions of avenues to pursue?

Comment: What goes wrong when trying to improve your proof of the last property?

Comment: Basically everything. :-) There's no obvious way to extend it to get anything smaller. 

Comment: If it goes *that* wrong, then you should be able to prove that your space is not paracompact. :-)

Comment: Well, first off there's no way I can prove my space is not paracompact because it's not a single space, and I know all paracompact spaces qualify. :-) But additionally the problem is that (as mentioned elsewhere) it's a parameterised property. The choice of parameter for the case locally < k isn't usefully shrinkable.

Comment: To elaborate, the proof of shrinkability is the one I think most likely to be extendable. The construction is clearly providing more than I'm using in concluding shrinkability (because I can demonstrate that it also rules out $\omega_1$, which *is* shrinkable), but I can't get a handle on how much more.

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2042368%20%22Shrinkable%20covers%22) has some theorems on shrinkable covers, which might be helpful. It's pretty close to normality, it seems (I knew that we can shrink locally finite covers in normal spaces). [This book](http://books.google.nl/books?id=D2k4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=every+open+cover+can+be+shrunk+to+a+closed+cover&source=bl&ots=MGGFNoiv-M&sig=XKPqI_nmlGovN-VDEKo0JIj8pnA&hl=nl&ei=MF_NS7XKI8ObOL-fpJ4P&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBsQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=every%2520open%2520cover%2520can%2520be%2520shrunk%2520to%2520a%2520closed%2520cover&f=false) has some connections to $\kappa$-Dowker spaces that might be useful.
It is mentioned that Navy's space is also shrinking (i.e. has your fourth property), so it might be a candidate counterexample.

Comment: Your link to the paper seems to be broken. Do you mean it to be http://www.jstor.org/pss/2042368 ? Also, could I impose on you to upload the jstor paper to drop.io or similar? I can't get access to very easily.

Caryn Navy's spaces all fail to be collectionwise normal, so they don't serve as a counterexample for the whole collection of properties. (by the way, I don't know if you saw my comment on the other answer, but I uploaded a scan of her thesis: http://drmaciver.com/docs/paracompactness-in-paralindelof-spaces.pdf ).

Comment: By the way, I think shrinkability is a reasonable amount stronger than normality. It seems to be about the level of strength of a condition as collectionwise normality (although I think neither implies the other)

Comment: I don't have access either, sorry. A disadvantage of not being in academia anymore... I'll see if more can be found on shrinkability. It seems indeed quite strong. I did get your uploaded Navy paper, thanks. 

Comment: Ah, I beg your pardon. I hadn't realised you also weren't in academia any longer. Never mind, I can swing by the British library on the way home and get access to it there. 

Comment: Annoyingly I couldn't manage to get an electronic copy at the library. Initial perusal of the paper isn't very encouraging, but will report back on reading it further.

Comment: http://books.google.nl/books?id=m0deV_61e5oC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=topology+shrinkable+space+paracompact+cover&source=bl&ots=MGMDSPddyt&sig=eY5ip6f0_SJvFPtbq8A1dcouL9k&hl=nl&ei=BQjOS9GnApaJOLfXxdsP&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=topology%20shrinkable%20space%20paracompact%20cover&f=false also seems relevant. Your last property seems related to property B there, e.g., so in particular countable paracompactness is already implied, it seems. All ordered spaces are shrinkable, which is nice, as are all perfectly normal spaces. 

Comment: http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v08/tp08104.pdf seems interesting too, maybe even alone for the proof techniques.

Comment: Yeah, the proof of locally < k and countable paracompactness are basically identical. One enumerates the open cover and for each x shrinks the cover in such a way that it doesn't appear in "too many" of them. 

Comment: I'm not sure if the second link is relevant, but it does seem interesting, thanks!

Comment: Actually looking at the proof again, it doesn't need any restrictions on the cofinality of k after all. It works for any infinite k. So it works the same for countable paracompactness and uncountable k.

Comment: (that is, it works for showing that it's locally < k. And locally < $\omega$ is the same as locally finite, so it implies countable paracompactness)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's always compact or Lindelof + T3. I actually made a graph about that!

[image: Graph of compactness properties]

Beyond that... Well, from *counterexamples in topology* we find out that:

Fully Normal -> Paracompact

T2 + Fully T4 -> Paracompact

As for my personal thoughts: there's probably some way to reverse paracompactness -> metacompactness:

Paracompact: Every open cover locally finite.
Metacompact: Every open cover point finite.

You'd need a pretty odd space to not have them be equivalent. Specifically: there exists some point with which every open cover has finite intersections but any open set containing it has non-finite intersections...

I suppose a non-finite number of sets approach each point from different directions so that they don't overlap too much? If you think about that in terms of dimensions, it's very weird. $\mathbb{R}^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Compact and lindelof aren't options. The properties I'm working with are all implied by paracompactness, so anything stronger than paracompactness isn't possible to prove. 

Metacompactness / weak paracompactness might be an option - they're equivalent propeties for collectionwise normal spaces - but so far I've not had any luck in proving them. 

Comment: Oops. I read "suggestions of avenues to pursue" as an opening for any property...

Perhaps you might list the properties you are working with?

Comment: It requires a fair bit of machinery to explain the properties. Essentially it's a parameterized property we're calling OCA(V), where V is a normed space. The property is basically designed to let you construct continuous functions from X into V.